# How to bring raise during probation review

Tags: united-kingdom, raise, probation

I was made redundant some time ago, and I had a hard time finding work. During that 3 month gap, I was offered a job at 8k p.a. less than my previous role, but something is better than nothing. The recruiter made my manager aware of it, and my manager told me that after probation my pay would be boosted to match my previous role's salary if I was good.

One month later COVID-19 hit, and we were all remote. No 1-on-1 meetings, no chats, or follow ups. [This post](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/124323/quitting-during-probation-period) resonates with me, but despite me raising this issue, it has fallen upon deaf ears. I called the recruiter and he said that it's all on me, but hasn't heard any negative feedback.

We're currently in the final stretch before launching the product, and I'm concerned about the pay match. My salary currently doesn't cover my expenses, and my family depends on me for that.

How, and when, should I bring this up with my manager? COVID-19 has disrupted the financial sector, and I don't want to sound greedy as it might impact my review.

I'm looking for an answer because if things aren't looking good, I want to start looking elsewhere.

Comment: Do you have anything *in writing* about matching your pay after probation?

Comment: @PhilipKendall no, I have to check with a recruiter he might on email

Comment: What is 121? And which currency?

Comment: @guest I have added more info in question about 121. currency is GBP

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: @gnat bit but my focus is more how to work around asking for the promised match meanwhile the world is dealing with COVID19 and what if he say no in retro to that

Comment: @JoeStrazzere End of this month but taking from my previous experience, they can be as relaxed in not discussing it until they want to but it is affecting my finances e.g. I cannot afford to send my son to school or pay for car.

Comment: "but despite me raising this issue" - did you speak with the manager or only the recruiter?

Comment: @PhilipKendall the recruiter doesn't have it as it was verbal so I asked manager if we can talk about probation n raise as it was discussed by recruiter with u.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> One month later COVID-19 hit, and we were all remote. No 1-on-1 meetings, no chats, or follow ups.

**Being remote does not mean your meetings with your manager should stop.**

If you previously had scheduled 1:1 meetings, these *should* be continuing. If you didn't have scheduled meetings but were promised an individual meeting, follow up and try to get this meeting set up.

Maybe the company is not doing well financially. You can try to fish for this by saying (via IM/email) to your boss:

> Hey boss, last month I asked you about my probationary period and a pay increase and we haven't had that conversation. Can I schedule a meeting with you about this?

If the company is financially sound and you have a competent boss, they *should* have this meeting with you relatively promptly. If you get ignored, follow up again after a few days/a week and if you get ignored again, start updating your resume.

The contents of the actual pay raise conversation is already covered in the linked questions/answers.

Comment: Now another problem arise. I been given a task that exploded and has kept me too busy. There has been quick chats about overtime and manager is fine with it, we r rebranding which was delayed by COVID-19 but now launch date is same my probation ends now I don't know if to ask or should complete my task and if to pass launch date to ask but then I don't have any time left to prep for new jobs

Comment: You can always ask your manager if you are *meeting their expectations*. If you feel the company owes you something such as a pay increase, you can also always ask about that regardless of what you are working on at any given moment. There is always work that company can assign you.

Comment: I was always under impression of the manager says, "not now" coz of deadline or important task and I m bringing pay/probation and whilst he might ask, why is X taking so long and it will go against me.

Comment: The company could be knowingly, and willingly, underpaying you.

Comment: update: no reply from manager on that email but everything else and they r also hiring another one who was hired pre covid-19 and now gonna onboard. so time for me to strap up Only problem is I m very unmotivated to do any work coz of lack in exchange of convo