# Feeling unmotivated to do work due to correspondence

Tags: professionalism, communication

Lately, I been very unmotivated to work/complete task. I posted a post [here](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/159644/how-to-bring-raise-during-probation-review) about how to bring probation topic with the manager whilst the company is preparing for a launch. I followed the advice as last month I asked my manager and he said he would get back to me but 2 weeks back I fired another email to email asking if we can talk as the post answer suggest but not reply.

However there has been group zoom chat and in it, it was mentioned that the company would be hiring another dev on my level (this was already decided pre-COVID-19) but now he is joining. Is there anything left me to ask the manager or will I be pushing him to make a decision on my pay raise given my situation or should I start sending out my CV? The reason I m so anxious is at a current job I cannot afford my son fee and had been under a crushing debt

Comment: When does your probation period end?

Comment: @HenryM first week of august

Answer (score 5):

I once worked at a big company where management was telling everyone to try and save money due to financial issues. So I didn't push my manager to do my review which is what determined when I was getting a raise. I felt that with the company in financial difficulties I shouldn't ask. Maybe 6 months after I should have had my review, I mentioned it to my boss and he says, 'Wow! You should have told me six months ago. I totally forgot all about it. I would have given you a raise then.'  I'd describe the look on his face as somewhere between very satisfied and trying not to laugh.

Worked at a small company where there were just two of us developers. I was promised a big bonus. When it came time for the bonus the owner of the company hired 10 new people (tech support) and told me that he couldn't afford to give me my bonus... and that I shouldn't be upset because we're all on the same team! Side note (?): Same guy had a ~$10 million beachfront mansion

The point is that the only person who is going to look out for you is **you**. Look at the calendar.. make sure you talk to the boss in time for you to get your raise on August 1st. And if you know you need more money then, sure you need to get it somewhere.